# Mutating the array gives NULL as the first entry

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**QUESTION**
Given an integer n and an array a of length n, your task is to apply the following mutation to a:

Array a mutates into a new array b of length n.
For each i from 0 to n - 1, b[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1].
If some element in the sum a[i - 1] + a[i] + a[i + 1] does not exist, it should be set to 0. For example, b[0] should be equal to 0 + a[0] + a[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi8FH.png).

**CODE**

```js
function mutateTheArray(n, a) {
    let b = []

    for(i=0; i <= n-1; i++){
        if(i==0){
            b[0] = a[0] + a[1]
        }
        if(i == n-1){
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i]
        }
        else{
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1]
        }
    }
    return b
}
console.log(mutateTheArray(5, [4, 0, 1, -2, 3]));
```

**RESULT**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi8FH.png)

Why is the first entry NULL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, output, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Side note: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) -- be sure to declare your variables.

Comment: The array is declared above the loop

Comment: I should have been more clear: `i` is the undeclared variable I'm talking about.

Comment: *"Why is the first entry NULL?"* It isn't. I don't know what's showing that output, but the first entry's value is `NaN`, not `null`. See the runnable snippet I put your code in.([Here's how to do one for next time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).)

Comment: The first element is `NaN`, not `null`. `null` is shown there because the array is stringified as JSON by some other code.

Comment: The problem is that on the first pass, you assign to `b[0]` twice, and the second time you're trying to use `a[-1]` in the calculation, which will convert to `NaN` when used as a number, which will make the entire calculation result for that first pass result in `NaN`. The first assignment is in the initial `if` block; the second is later in the `else` on the subsequent `if`. You need `else` before your second `if` so that if the first one's condition matches, the second one isn't tried.

Comment: Another side note: It's **totally** a matter of style, but `i < n` is more common (I'd even say idiomatic) than `i <= n - 1`.

Comment: Moving the else before the second if worked

Comment: Side note: the assignment has an oxymoron: *"Array a mutates into a new array b"*. Either the array *mutates*, or a *new* array is created. The term *"mutation"* is misused here, but the exercise would be more interesting if true mutation was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is performing the following logic

- If it is the *first* element: do ***A***
- If it is the *last* element: do ***B***, otherwise (e.g. when it is the first one!!): do ***C***.

So on the first iteration, your code is performing both ***A*** and ***C***!

You should not execute ***C*** in the first iteration.

**You miss `else if`**

#### Correction:

```js
function mutateTheArray(n, a) {
    let b = [];

    for (let i=0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        if (i==0) {
            b[0] = a[0] + a[1];
        } else if (i == n-1) { // <- here
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i];
        } else {
            b[i] = a[i-1] + a[i] + a[i+1];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
console.log(mutateTheArray(5, [4, 0, 1, -2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(n, a) {
    let b = [];
     if (n == 1) {
       return a;
   }
   

    for(let i=0; i<=n-1; i++){
        if(i == 0){
            b[i] = a[i] + a[i+1];
        }else if(i == n-1){
            b[i] = a[i-1]+ a[i]+0;
        }else{
            b[i] = a[i-1]+ a[i]+ a[i+1];
        }
    }
    return b;

}
console.log(solution(5, [4, 0, 1, -2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] solution(int[] a) {
    int[] b = new int[a.Length];
    for(int i=0; i<a.Length; i++)
    {
        if(i== a.Length -1)
        {
            if(i - 1 >= 0)
                b[i] = a[i-1]+a[i];
            else
                b[i] = 0 + a[i];
        }
        else if(i==0)
        {
             if(i+1 < a.Length)
                b[i] = a[i] + a[i+1];
            else
                b[i] = a[i] +0;
        }
        else
        {
            b[i] = a[i-1]+a[i]+a[i+1];
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).